# Tensorflow 1.x to Tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, softmax, conv-neural-network

I am trying to update code written in Tensorflow 1.x to code in Tensorflow 2.1.0. I have been converting codes using Tensorflow 2.1.0 documentation, and I had no problems until this code.

```
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(one_hot_labels, logits)
```

Above code is Tensorflow 1.x version, and I think, according to Tensorflow 2.1.0 documentation, the properly updated code is

```
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(one_hot_labels, logits)
```

Then, when I run

```
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

I get the following error.

```
Loss must be scalar, given: Tensor("softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_2:0", shape=(512,), dtype=float32)**
```

So, I am guessing in Tensorflow 1.x version, the loss was passed as 'tensor' to tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec, but in Tensorflow 2.1.0, the loss has to be passed as `scalar` to `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec`? Loss (the way it is defined here) in both Tensorflow 1.x and 2.1.0 is tensor if I remember it correctly.

So, does anyone know how to convert tensor to scalar (which I don't think will be sufficient nor efficient in building the CNN model) or better yet, how to solve this dilemma?

Or did I convert the original code the wrong way?

I would very much appreciate if compat.v1. is not used unless absolutely necessary (i.e. no other way to use the code in Tensorflow 2.1.0 than compat.v1.)

Comment: can you try with `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy` instead?

Comment: @learner If I use ```tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy```, would the parameters be label and predict? And do I need to add .numpy() at the end of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just average the result (which is what `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` did anyway through `tf.losses.compute_weighted_loss`):

```py
loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(one_hot_labels, logits))
```